# Windows + Programs on an external hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I have a few computers at home (a desktop and a couple of old pcs) and was wanting to centralise my programs and data so that I don't need to keep copying stuff from one to another.

I was thinking about getting an SSD external hard drive to install Windows and all my programs on so that I could always work from there.

I think it's possible, but I wonder about performance... Would there be any limitations to using all of the available computer resources (either the desktop or one of the pcs)?
Has any of you ever trying this configuration?

My main uses are Office, DAW, and some games (not too resource intensive).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed run Windows on an external drive. I did that once on a SanDisk Extreme Pro to make Win10 run external on my MacBook. The performance was really good, but depend on the speed and quality of the external drive you installed Windows on.
I can recommend the SanDisk Drives for your Purpose, but the have USB-C Connection.
Search WindowsToGo in your favorite search engine and you find some installation instructions.

Wish you the best, stay healthy!

Comment: Hi Marcelino, thanks for the info. Glad to know it work properly.